# Populate Mailto link with multiple email addresses from database

Tags: asp.net, mailto, asp.net-webpages

I would like to create email distribution lists of users in the database. My thought was to populate Mailto links with the users in each list.

This is what I have tried:

```
var selectEmail = db.Query("SELECT Email FROM Users");
```

Add a Mailto link:

```
<a href="mailto:@foreach (var row in selectEmail){@row.Email}">Email everyone</a>
```

The issue is that this goes into the email like: `email1@example.comemail2@example.com`.

I need it to be comma delimited, like this: `email1@example.com, email1@example.com`

Any thoughts on correcting this or suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If selectEmail is Enumerable, you can use [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) to connect string values with comma.

```
<a href="mailto:@string.Join(",", Model.SelectEmail)">Email everyone</a>
```